# ImportError: No module named <module_name>

Tags: python, module, pydev, python-2.7

I'm a Java programmer and I began to develop some modules in python.
I tried to divide the layers of abstraction with packages, but, unfortunatelly there's a class at the root package (hokuspokus.py) trying to acess some
classes at the inner packages (videofactory.py), and it raises the error ImportError: No module named media.videofactory.

I also made a test where all my files were on a same package (hokuspokus) and everything runned just fine :(

I'm using Python 2.7, Windows and Aptana Studio 3 with PyDev.

I checked my PYTHONPATH and the root folder of the project was there as a source folder.
I created a google code project with all my code for this module and pydev configs : http://code.google.com/p/hokuspokus-py/source/checkout

```
Package Structure:
HokusPokus (source folder)
|
----hokuspokus (root package)
    |
    --- media (inner package)
    |   |
    |   ----videofactory.py
    |
    |
    ---- hokuspokus.py
```

Comment: +1 For actually providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and even linking to it. However, I can't find `hokuspokus/media/mediafactory.py`.

Comment: Do you get the error when the running the code from Aptana Studio or from the shell?

Comment: @burhan I runnning from Aptana

Comment: @phihag Sorry, I put the example of my local project. I updated the names to match the code at google.

Comment: `media` directory contains `videofactory.py` file which contains `VideoFactory` Class.. no such `mediafactory.py` is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
from media.videofactory import VideoFactory
```

import the concrete class out of your module
if you wanna import all elements in your module u can use:

```
from media.videofactory import *
```

but its not the best way.

Comment: Yeah! It worked. Interesting, all my imports were done using the classic hotkey from eclipse CTRL+SHIFT+O, and for the root class it added `from hokuspokus.media.videofactory import VideoFactory`. I did like you said, I removed the root package (hokuspokus) from  importev and erything runned beautifully. Thanks